# Edge detection Gray image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

[image]i need some advice in a computer vision projekt that i am working on. I am trying to extract a corner in the image below[image: EDGE DETECTION IMAGE]. The edge im searching for is marked yellow in the right image. The edge detection is always failing because the edge is too blurred in the middle.
I run this process with opencv and python.

I started to remove the white dots with a threshold method. After that a big median blur (31-53). After that a adaptive Threshod method to seperate the areas left and right from the corners. But the sepearation is always bad because the edge is barely visible.

Is there some other way to extract this edge or do i have to try with a better camera?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First do you have other dataset? because it is hard to discuss it just from 1 input.

Couple things that you can do.

1. The best is you change the camera of imaging technique to have a better and clear edge.
2. When it is hard to do so. Try model-based fitting.If you image is repeatable in all class. I can observe some circles on the right and 2 sharp straight-line edges on the left. Your wanted red soft edge circle is in the middle of those 2 apparent features.  That can be considered as a model. then you can always use some other technique for the pixel in-between those 2 region(because they are easy to detect) . Those technique includes but not limit to histogram equalization, high pass filter or even wavelet transform.
3. The Wost way is to use parameter fitting to do. What you want to segment is sth not a strong edge and sth not a smooth plane. So you can tweak the canny edge detect to find those edge which is not so strong. I do not support this method. If you really no choice and no other image, then you can try it.
4. Last way is to use deep learning  based method to train and auto segment this part out. This method might work. but it needs you to have hundred if not thousands of dataset and labels.

Regards

Shenghai Yuan

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i added some images

Comment: The image is not repeatable. Every image looks a bit diiferent but thanks for the answer

Comment: try method 1 3 and 4. for non-repeatable pattern and hardware can not be improved. deep learning might be your only choice.